# NetworkChangeReceiver срабатывает 2 раза

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver, android-broadcastreceiver

При изменении подключения к интернету метод onReceive срабатывает 2 раза (Необходимо одно срабатывание).

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

boolean connection;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if ((wifi != null && wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting()) || (mobile != null && mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting())){
        connection = true;
    }

    if (connection) {
        Log.d("Network Available ", "YES");
    } else {
        Log.d("Network Available ", "NO");
    }
}
```

}

Результат в логе при выключении:

```
 D/Network Available: NO
 D/Network Available: NO
```

Соответственно при включении:

```
 D/Network Available: YES
`D/Network Available: YES
```

Comment: как вы в манифесте  его объявили?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш broadcastReciever срабатывает дважды, потому что вы имеете скорее всего два `<intent-filter>` 
для изменения интернет подключения

```
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
```

и для изменения состояния wi-fi

```
"<action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"
```

используйте только один

```
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
```

это должно решить вашу проблему, ресивер будет срабатывать только при изменении состояния интернет подключения

Comment: В манифесте у меня один intent-filter